# Can someone explain why amoebas are closed?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

From Wikipedia, [image]

**Claim: any amoeba is closed.**

I attempted to use the preimage of closed under continuous map is closed but I realized that my skill with complex functions was too feeble, so I found a proof instead

http://www.sciencesmaths-paris.fr/upload/Contenu/Notes%20et%20resumes%20cours/Notes_Cours_Mikhalkin/lecture-notes1.pdf

[image]

Can someone use simple language or a series of simple propositions to explain what the proof is trying to do? If I were to attempt to use the standard proof: the preimage of closed set under continuous map is closed, what are the necessary ingredients contained in this proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the continuous preimage of a closed set is closed. This is just a general fact of topology:

- $A$ is closed iff (by definition) its complement $A^c$ is open.
- $f$ is continuous iff (by definition) the $f$-preimage of any open set is open.
- The complement of the preimage is the preimage of the complement. (Exercise)

However, this isn't what you want: you want that the *image* of a closed set is closed (since you're trying to go from $V$ to $Log(V)$, and you know the former is closed). This is in general **false**: for example, consider the map $arctan(x)$ as a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Is the $f$-image of the closed set $\mathbb{R}$ a closed set?

A map which sends closed sets to closed sets is called (unsurprisingly) **closed**, and in general continuous maps need not be closed and closed maps need not be continuous.

This seems to rule out an easy proof . . .

---

. . . so we're going to have to be more clever. What *other* properties does $Log$ have?

Well, the crucial observation is:

> The map $Log: (\mathbb{C}^\times)^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ is **proper** (that is, preimages of compact sets are compact).

This isn't hard to show: a compact set in either $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^N$ or $\mathbb{R}^N$ is just a closed and bounded set, so it's enough to show that the $Log$-preimage of a bounded set is bounded since $Log$ is continuous.

OK, so what? Well, it turns out that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous proper map *and $Y$ is locally compact* (in fact, we only need the weaker condition that $Y$ be "compactly generated," but that's a bit more technical), then $f$ is closed! I won't prove this here, since we don't need it; I'll just prove that any continuous proper map between two locally compact metric spaces is closed.

- Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous proper map between two locally compact metric spaces, and $A\subseteq X$ is some closed set. Let $y\in\overline{A}$ (where "$\overline{\cdot}$" denotes "closure"); then for each natural number $i$, let $U_i$ be a compact subset of $Y$ containing $y$ with diameter $<2^{-i}$, and let $W_i=f^{-1}(U_i)\cap A$.
- Since $y$ is on the boundary of $f(A)$, $W_i\not=\emptyset$ for any $i$. So pick $x_i\in W_i$.
- Since $f$ is proper, $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is compact, and so the sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence. Without loss of generality, suppose the whole sequence converges, and call its limit point $z$.
- Since $A$ is closed, $z\in A$. But do you see how to show now that $f(z)=y$?